# How does one use 4 pulldown selections to display a result text?

Tags: forms

If I need to use 4 different drop boxes and the value of each dropbox selection which when combined would allow me to equate a textbox output --how would I do that?

I select from drop box 1, then from dropbox 2, then from dropbox 3, then from dropbox 4 and the combined selections (if `drpbx1selected value = 1`, and `drpbx2selected value=3`, and...) allows me to assign a text output to it?

I set each dropdown list in a form with a Function Option1,2,3,4 and a variable of sel1,2,3,and 4 to indicate the selected 4 possible values:

```
function setOption1(chosen) {
    if (chosen == "1") {
        var e1 = document.getElementById("e27");
        var sel1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
    }
    else if (chosen == "2") {
        var e2 = document.getElementById("e27");
        var sel2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
    }
}
```

I then used the selx variable of the functions to display the part number resulting from the 4 selected values. Here's where I'm stuck --I don't know what to use to be able to display the part number derived from the four values. There are 15 possible part numbers with 15 possible value selections.

```
function displaysel()
if (sel1 == "1" , sel3 == "3", sel7 == "7", sel9 == "9") {
    var partno = "600-618";
}
```

I am new at this and really need to get this resolved. Any help is appreciated!!